# Google visualization line chart missing Y axis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am new to javascript and the Google Visualization library. I've created a line chart as below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R5lH.png), but cannot get the Y Axis to display anything; I'm looking for the axis itself to be drawn, along with the values from the Data Table.

Here's my code (the chart labels are changed from the screenshot, but nothing more):

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);
function drawLineChart(){var data=google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [
        [
            'Day',
            'Label 1','Label 2','Label 3','Label 4','Label 5',
            'Label 6','Label 7','Label 8','Label 9','Label 10',
        ],
        ['19 Aug 2013',1,0,0,0,0,0],
        ['20 Aug 2013',2,2,2,0,0,0],
        ['21 Aug 2013',5,5,0,6,5,0],
        ['22 Aug 2013',1,4,3,2,0,0],
        ['23 Aug 2013',0,0,0,4,0,0],
        ['24 Aug 2013',3,2,1,2,0,15],
        ['25 Aug 2013',1,2,1,2,0,0],
        ['26 Aug 2013',3,1,2,1,0,0],
        ['27 Aug 2013',0,0,3,2,0,1]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title:'Title',
        legend:{position:'bottom'},
        curveType:'none',
        interpolateNulls:true,
        chartArea:{left:0,top:10,width:"100%"}
    };

    var chart=new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visits_by_day1'));chart.draw(data,options);}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer that keeps the `chartArea.width` option at 100%: set the `vAxis.textPosition` option to "in", which will draw the labels inside the chartArea:

```
var options = {
    title:'Title',
    legend:{position:'bottom'},
    curveType:'none',
    interpolateNulls:true,
    chartArea:{left:0,top:10,width:"100%"},
    vAxis:{textPosition: 'in'}
};
```

That will give you the axis labels just inside the edge of the chartArea

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. You have extra labels you don't need. Your code, as written won't work at all. Strip the number of labels down to the number of columns you have.
2. Adding strings, and hoping they're interpreted as dates doesn't work well. Make it explicit.
3. Your chart area also excluded the vAxis labels.

Try the following:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Label 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Label 2');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Label 3');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Label 4');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Label 5');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Label 6');
  data.addRows([
        [new Date('19 Aug 2013'),1,0,0,0,0,0],
        [new Date('20 Aug 2013'),2,2,2,0,0,0],
        [new Date('21 Aug 2013'),5,5,0,6,5,0],
        [new Date('22 Aug 2013'),1,4,3,2,0,0],
        [new Date('23 Aug 2013'),0,0,0,4,0,0],
        [new Date('24 Aug 2013'),3,2,1,2,0,15],
        [new Date('25 Aug 2013'),1,2,1,2,0,0],
        [new Date('26 Aug 2013'),3,1,2,1,0,0],
        [new Date('27 Aug 2013'),0,0,3,2,0,1]
    ]);

  var options = {
      title:'Title',
      legend:{position:'bottom'},
      curveType:'none',
      interpolateNulls:true,
      //chartArea:{left:0,top:10,width:"100%"}
  };

  var chart=new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visits_by_day1'));
  chart.draw(data,options);
}
​
```

Comment: I would recommend staying away from using the format `new Date('19 Aug 2013')`, as date conversion from strings is inconsistent across browsers.  Use `new Date (2013, 7, 19)` (months are zero-indexed, so August is 7, not 8).

Comment: Thanks. The labels was a typo on editing for SO. I'm just using a date as a label; I'm not expecting any conversion. What's the advantage of using a "real" date value? Removing `chartArea: {left:0,top:10,width:'100%'}` reinstates the vertical axis, but Why?

Comment: @cdmh.  The `chartArea` is the portion of the chart reserved for graphing your data, and it excludes the axes and legend.  By setting the chartArea width to 100%, you made it so that the API didn't have any place to draw the axis labels.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue. But, in my case, I am NOT using chartArea option at all. Hence, I doubt @asgallant's explanation is correct.

The following is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    // Declare columns
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'MM8');
    data.addColumn('number', 'S&P');
    
    data.addRows([[new Date('01/03/2017'),98517.96,100278.03],[new Date('01/10/2017'),99606.27,100769.69],[new Date('01/17/2017'),97409.55,100724.83],[new Date('01/24/2017'),101596.78,101265.78],[new Date('01/31/2017'),103283.59,101212.49],[new Date('02/07/2017'),106136.74,101843.6],[new Date('02/14/2017'),102568.42,103820.0],[new Date('02/21/2017'),102253.38,105054.7],[new Date('02/28/2017'),98587.77,104977.42],[new Date('03/07/2017'),97623.69,105188.38],[new Date('03/14/2017'),99571.71,105057.8],[new Date('03/21/2017'),98026.27,104106.02],[new Date('03/28/2017'),100641.93,104752.24],[new Date('04/04/2017'),98556.17,104822.86],[new Date('04/11/2017'),99200.09,104539.5],[new Date('04/18/2017'),98695.49,104024.75],[new Date('04/25/2017'),102622.71,106086.42],[new Date('05/02/2017'),100472.95,106200.12],[new Date('05/09/2017'),98574.4,106455.5],[new Date('05/16/2017'),106159.07,106622.05],[new Date('05/23/2017'),104296.55,106522.12],[new Date('05/30/2017'),105035.88,107165.67],[new Date('06/06/2017'),107811.48,107894.94],[new Date('06/13/2017'),110670.8,108384.37],[new Date('06/20/2017'),110152.66,108236.92],[new Date('06/27/2017'),109044.62,107453.02],[new Date('07/03/2017'),108633.82,107880.72],[new Date('07/11/2017'),111239.13,107726.16],[new Date('07/18/2017'),113238.32,109284.19],[new Date('07/25/2017'),114516.89,110017.9],[new Date('08/01/2017'),114235.76,109983.26],[new Date('08/08/2017'),118583.33,109919.74],[new Date('08/15/2017'),117029.48,109461.84],[new Date('08/22/2017'),115461.52,108924.44],[new Date('08/29/2017'),113553.88,108648.63],[new Date('09/05/2017'),112772.29,109161.61],[new Date('09/12/2017'),113241.54,110877.3],[new Date('09/19/2017'),116056.94,111328.98],[new Date('09/26/2017'),114991.2,110893.29],[new Date('10/03/2017'),119650.15,112569.45],[new Date('10/10/2017'),119326.16,113282.73],[new Date('10/17/2017'),124032.6,113670.02],[new Date('10/24/2017'),125599.48,114103.94],[new Date('10/31/2017'),126408.48,114376.19],[new Date('11/07/2017'),126213.65,115059.27],[new Date('11/14/2017'),128414.88,114536.52],[new Date('11/21/2017'),132050.66,115431.9],[new Date('11/28/2017'),133242.73,116675.92],[new Date('12/05/2017'),130042.14,116788.29],[new Date('12/12/2017'),130220.51,118322.33],[new Date('12/19/2017'),133182.72,119093.34],[new Date('12/26/2017'),133313.89,119050.26],[new Date('01/02/2018'),133892.53,119730.23]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Portfolio Performance Comparison',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'M/d/yy'
        }
     };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

[resulted graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1fQL.png)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31023893)